# what is message box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

what in asp.net similar to message box

```
if (s != "null")
   MessageBox.Show("your in ");
else
   MessageBox.Show("wrong user ");
```

i want to replace message box here in c# code

Comment: Could you edit the text so that the code also includes If(s != "null")? ;))

Answer (score 2):

There is no message box as such in asp.net. The nearest thing to this kind of functionality will be a javascript alert box.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a server side technology. The whole C#/VB/etc. code will be executed on the server and the response (which is probably HTML/JS/...) will be sent to the client.

You could send out the necessary Jscript code to display a message box on the client. Note that this code will not be executed immediately, but will be sent to the browser. The browser will interpret it and display the message box accordingly.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   alert('Hi');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct equivalent. The MessageBox class is a Windows Forms class.

In ASP .NET, a JavaScript alert would be most commonly used for the same purpose.

This runs on the client, so you would need to emit the javascript in the generated html, if you need to control the message serverside.

Answer (score 0):

For confirmations you could use the [Confirm button](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx) from ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly useful method of emitting javascript alerts from the code-behind in ASP.NET and modified it some. I don't know if it is an ideal solution or not, but you should just have to paste the function in your code-behind (the example is in VB).

```
Private Sub MessageBox(ByVal msg As String)
    Dim lbl As New Label()
    lbl.Text = "<script type="text/javascript">" & Environment.NewLine & _
               "window.alert('" + msg + "')</script>"
    Page.Controls.Add(lbl)
End Sub
```

To use, you would just call `MessageBox("Here is your Input")`.

Comment: The language attribute is obsolete. Use type="text/javascript".

Comment: Good catch. Seems like I copy/pasted this one from an older project I had been doing some maintenance on.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the client script manager to run a Javascript when the page loads, which shows an alert box to the user:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "message", "window.alert('You are in.');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to confirm an action you can use the onclientclick property of a button

```
<asp:button Id="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm Me" OnClick="MyFunction" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are your sure?')" />
```